# How can I copy a value from server to client in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

On Google Earth Engine, suppose I have a Number on the server side. How can I get it as an integer on the client side?

```
var x = ee.Number(42)
typeof(x)  //  yields "object", i.e. server side

var y = ??? // what function of x will get me a local 42 in y?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work, although it is not recommended by the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server?hl=en):

```
var x = ee.Number(42)  // server side variable

var z = x.getInfo()  // local string

var y = parseInt(z)
```